# Angular wildcard routing instead of empty route

Tags: angular, routes

When the app loads or the browser is refreshed it loads my HomepageComponent, but when i try to redirect to an empty route after navigating through the app, it is taking the wildcard route and staying in the CategoriesComponent. So I can't route back to the homepage with out refreshing. Any ideas?

**app.routing.ts**

```
   {
    path      : '',
    pathMatch : 'full',
    component : HomepageComponent
  },
  {
    path      : 'users',
    component : UsersComponent
  },
  {
    path      : 'users/:group',
    component : UsersComponent
  },
  {
    path      : 'user/:id',
    component : UserDetailComponent
  },
  {
    path       : 'user',
    redirectTo : 'users'
  },
  {
    path      : 'page-not-found',
    component : ErrorComponent
  },
  {
    path      : '**', // Wildcard for sub-category processing
    component : CategoriesComponent
  }
```

Comment: can you attach the code when you redirect to an empty route?

Comment: It's simply : 
window.history.back();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that I am necroing this post, but I ran into this issue recently and found a solution. I moved my empty path to the end of the array and it worked.

I believe this happens because you are using `pathMatch: 'full'` which changes the default `pathmatch: 'prefix'` matching behavior. *Prefix* stops at the first match, whereas *full* looks through the entire array. Since there is a valid match (**) after the blank path it chooses wildcard instead.

Moving the blank path javascript object to the end of your array should change this behavior.

### app.routing.ts

```
  {
    path      : 'users',
    component : UsersComponent
  },
  {
    path      : 'users/:group',
    component : UsersComponent
  },
  {
    path      : 'user/:id',
    component : UserDetailComponent
  },
  {
    path       : 'user',
    redirectTo : 'users'
  },
  {
    path      : 'page-not-found',
    component : ErrorComponent
  },
  {
    path      : '**', // Wildcard for sub-category processing
    component : CategoriesComponent
  },
  {
    path      : '', // Moved below the wildcard path
    pathMatch : 'full',
    component : HomepageComponent
  },
```